# Getting what is the first day of the week based on Locale with momentJs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Using momentJs, is possible to get the first day of the week (Monday(1), Sunday(7)...) based on Locale without creating a new moment?

I know I can access what is the first day of the week for the current locale with:

```
moment.locale('uk');
moment().startOf('week').isoWeekday(); //Returns 1
moment.locale('en');
moment().startOf('week').isoWeekday(); //Returns 7
```

But I think it's a bit ugly...

1. Creating a momentjs object.
2. Going to the first date of the week.
3. Resolving the weekDay.

Any better idea?
Thx!

Comment: Please check version of moment.js.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This question has a proper answer in momentjs's current API:

```
moment.localeData('en-us').firstDayOfWeek();
```

As OP asked - no instance of moment() needed, also no ugliness of going to "start of", just plain simple use of their localeData.

Note, that it might be required to download the moment+locale file which is significantly larger (44kb) than moment only (about 12kb).

Seems to be the case from version 2.2.0, more info can be found on their docs:
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/locale-data/

Answer (score 4):

Looks to me that you wanted to get a locale aware start of week (`startOf('week')`) and return its value as an `isoWeekday`, not the date or anything? In that case your question is the answer.

```
moment().startOf('week').isoWeekday();
```

Comment: Please, refer to my question requirement: "without creating a moment object"

Comment: Oh sorry, now  i see. Afaik moment is supposed to work like that and I don't find it that ugly... Where the need from?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can just do moment().locale('us').weekday(0) as of version 2.1.0
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/weekday/

Comment: When I say 'first day' I mean Monday(1)/Sunday(7), not a date.That returns a moment that is the first day of the week. Basically is the same than doing moment().locale('us').startOf('week')

Comment: This solves it because each language has a first day of the week, in the US that day is Sunday where as in Europe is Monday. With that function you get the fist day of the week in the locale you pass as parameter